# Can I rely on the synchronous nature of resolved jquery deferred objects

Tags: jquery, synchronous, jquery-deferred

> **Please Note:** This question was about why the jQuery implementation of promises does not follow the Promises/A+ specification with regards to [requirement 2.2.4](http://promisesaplus.com/#point-34).

---

I have noticed that once a [jQuery deferred object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) has been resolved, new calls to [done](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/) will have any doneCallbacks called synchronously.

```
var d = $.Deferred();

d.resolve("Foo Bar!");

var fooBar = "Waiting";

d.done(function(data){fooBar = data; });

console.log(fooBar);//Will output "Foo Bar!" because the doneCallback is called synchronously
```

I had expected the callbacks to be put on the event queue (in which case the output to the console would have been "Waiting"), so as to match the behavior of calling done before the deferred object is resolved. Is my expectation unreasonable?

I couldn't seem to find any documentation around this behavior though, so I am unsure if this is a behavior I can rely on.

Comment: *"[When the Deferred is resolved, the doneCallbacks are called.](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/)"* How much more explicit should the documentation be?

Comment: @Jon I guess it wasn't very clear in the question, but I am asking about the callbacks passed to the deferred object being called synchronously. This seems to happen if done is called after the deferred object has been resolved.  I understand what you quoted from the docs.  I was looking for something that said:  "If the deferred object has already been resolved, when calling done, the doneCallbacks will happen synchronously".  If they were executed asynchronously, "Foo Bar!" would never be output to the console.  I will try to edit the question.

Comment: Yes, the behaviour is thoroughly reliable. A good way to get your mind round it is to understand (a) that a Deferred's callback queues are managed internally with instances of jQuery's [`Callbacks`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Callbacks/), and (b) that these `Callbacks` instances are initialised with flags `memory once`. Get your mind round these flags and the behaviour of `.done()`, `.fail()` and `.always()` should be totally clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is documented explicitly here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.deferred/

> Once the object has entered the resolved or rejected state, it stays in that state. Callbacks can still be added to the resolved or rejected Deferred — they will execute immediately.

Comment: That documentation (as discussed in comments above) neither explicitly nor implicitly addresses the specific behavior being asked about.

Comment: Ah good find! I see you updated your answer with a different quote and a different link.  This is indeed what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue you need to be concerned about here is "scope".
This is assuming I am understanding your question here. You are curious why "Waiting" is not being set because is seemingly comes after your resolve.

For instance.. you have this snippet here:

```
    var d = $.Deferred();
    d.resolve("Foo Bar!");
    var fooBar = "Waiting";
    d.done(function(data){fooBar = data; });
    console.log(fooBar)
```

What does that give?

Now we have this:

```
    var d = $.Deferred();
    var fooBar = "Waiting";
    d.done(function(data){fooBar = data; });
    console.log(fooBar)
    d.resolve("Foo Bar!");
```

and this:

```
    var d = $.Deferred();
    d.done(function(data){fooBar = data; });
    d.resolve("Foo Bar!");
    var fooBar = "Waiting";
    console.log(fooBar)
```

Now check this out!

```
var d = $.Deferred();
console.log( fooBar);
d.resolve("Foo Bar!");
var fooBar = "Waiting";
console.log( fooBar);
d.done(function(data){fooBar = data; });
console.log(fooBar)
```

Think about **hoisting** and **scope**.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I am not sure you understood the question though.  I added a note to the question to clarify what I am asking about.  This question is about the difference between jQuery promises and the Promises/A+ specification, specifically [requirement 2.2.4](http://promisesaplus.com/#point-34).